# Struggle about binary files

Tags: c++, file

Consider I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream output("Brojevi.dat");
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        output.write((char*)&i, sizeof(i));
    output.flush();
    ifstream input("Brojevi.dat");
    int broj;
    while(input.read((char*)&broj, sizeof(broj)))
        cout<<broj<<endl;
    input.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while(input.read((char*)&broj, sizeof(broj)))
        cout<<broj<<endl;
}
```

When i run this programm the output are numbers from 0 to 10 only once. I wonder why dont they print out twice since i got 2 same while loops. Any idea?

Comment: Marginally related: Read up on open modes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream You want binary for a binary file.

Comment: What version of c++ are you using? The behavior was changed with c++11 regarding the EOF bit. If you are with c++98 then `seekg` won't clear `eofbit`.

Comment: You should close an input file before opening the same file as output.  Or, open the file with `fstream` and make it read & write.

Answer (score 0):

first open the `output` and `input` in binary mode

```
ofstream output("Brojevi.dat",ios::binary);
ifstream input("Brojevi.dat",ios::binary);
```

after

```
int broj;
while(input.read((char*)&broj, sizeof(broj)))
cout<<broj<<endl;
```

add `input.clear()`
because in the above loop you have reached eof(), and after that, all input-output operation will be invalidated so you have to clear internal eof bit to continue your operations

working code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream output("Brojevi.dat",ios::binary);
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        output.write((char*)&i, sizeof(i));
    output.flush();
    ifstream input("Brojevi.dat",ios::binary);
    int broj;
    while(input.read((char*)&broj, sizeof(broj)))
        cout<<broj<<endl;
    input.clear();
    input.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while(input.read((char*)&broj, sizeof(broj)))
        cout<<broj<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Remember that there is more than just EOF. Though it's not likely with a binary read, you can find yourself exiting the loop over and clearing a different, unexpected error that you really should have taken a closer look at.

Comment: both fail and eof bit will be get set

Comment: Not what I meant. My apologies for being unclear. What I was trying to say is you may encounter an error where the failure has nothing whatsoever to do with reaching the end of the file.